# how to stop the code from being executed without exiting application in c#

Tags: c#

I have a windows forms application, I have implemented a project that should stop the execution without closing the application.I used environment.exit(0) to stop the execution but it closes the windows forms application.
for example I have a button in my windows forms application,

```
    buttnclick(obj sender,eventargs e)
    {
somefun();//calls somefun
otherfun();
    }
private void somefun()
{
if(smthng true)
    {
    //some code goes here
    }
    else
    {
    environment.exit(0);//closing the windows form but I don't want
//again I want to click the button to execute without closing windows forms
    }
}
```

any suggestions I am greatful.

Comment: Just `return` from your current method.

Comment: "stop the execution" of what? A thread? Or do you not want to run the `//some code goes here`?

Comment: Or just remove the entire `else` statement you will be returning after it anyway

Comment: sorry I edited my code please see it now

Answer (score 4):

replace `environment.exit(0);` with `return;`

Comment: Right answer. Notice that code in a *finally*-block is executed anyway (may not needed for this question, but maybe somebody has this issue in future).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `return` statement.

```
buttnclick(obj sender,eventargs e)
{
   if(smthng true)
   {
      //some code goes here
   }
   else
   {
      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Stop executing" is incorrect term here. Technically no process can stop *executing*. Even when none of your code is running, something somewhere keeps the program running, even if it be the very low-level message loop.

Remember whether you issue a `return`, or `exit`, the code will go back to the calling method. If it reaches the main method, a `return` will do the same thing as `exit`.